# fail set parent's parent's iframe height in firefox

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser, cross-domain, parent

## Background

The relationship and hierachy of this pages are :

-A.html                         (domain : domain1.com)

----B.html                      (domain : domain2.com)

--------C.html                  (domain : domain1.com)

what's more,

B.html was included inside A.html by means of Iframe (the id of iframe is "mainIframe");

C.html was included inside B.html by means of Iframe (the id of iframe is "proxyIframe");

## Issues

I have below functions in C.html(iframe with id "proxyIframe"):

```
function  updateHeight() {
    mainIframe = parent.parent.document.getElementById('mainIframe');
    newHeigh = parent.parent.frames["mainIframe"].frames["proxyIframe"].location.hash.substr(1);
    mainIframe.style.height = newHeigh;
}

function canUpdateHeight() {
    if(parent!=null && parent.parent!=null && parent.parent.document!=null &&
        parent.parent.document.getElementById('mainIframe')!=null && 
        parent.parent.frames["mainIframe"]!=null &&
        parent.parent.frames["mainIframe"].frames["proxyIframe"]!=null){
                 window.setInterval("updateHeight()", 200);
   }
}
```

The issues are : the checking inside the second function won't be passed, so that the first function also won't be triggered.
Please note that these function worked in IE7, Chrome11.x, Chrome16.x, Safari5.x, but have issues in Firefox.

## Question

What i want to do is make above functions work, but currently i have no idea what's the issues now. it's incorrect to use "parent.parent" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is you can't use `document.frames` in FF.
Also note that `parent` and `parent.parent` and `parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent` always exist, even if there are no frames, so I think a lot of those conditions are unnecessary.

Try:

```
function  updateHeight() {
    var mainIframe = parent.parent.document.getElementById('mainIframe'),
        mainDoc = mainIframe.contentDocument || mainIframe.contentWindow.document,
        proxyIframe = mainDoc.getElementById('proxyIframe'),
        proxyDoc = proxyIframe.contentDocument || proxyIframe.contentWindow.document;
    newHeigh = proxyDoc.location.hash.substr(1);
    mainIframe.style.height = newHeigh;
}

function canUpdateHeight() {
    if(parent.parent.document.getElementById('mainIframe')
      && parent.document.getElementById('proxyIframe')) {
        window.setInterval(updateHeight, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi wnwall, thanks for you quick answer. Indeed, checking the existence of parent is unnecessary as it always exists. For the approach to get frames, i didn't distinguish IE and FF. I will deploy the updating soonly, i think it should work, thanks again! i will notify you if it work.

Comment: Hi wnwall, faided at **parent.document.getElementById('proxyIframe')**, the firebug complain that **Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'**. I think you know the issue, as due to cross-domain, any ideas?

Comment: Ah, right, different domains. Well that's a different problem and not an easy one to solve, depending on how much control you have over each domain. If you have complete control over both, you should be able to get it working on all browsers, but get ready to roll your sleeves up :). This article looks like a good place to start: http://www.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/

Comment: Why is the height in the hash for the location of the proxyIframe? Could this value be stored somewhere in a frame with the same domain it's trying to be accessed by? Because it looks like the only thing you need to go cross-domain for is to get the height variable.

Comment: Hi, I finally make the issue fixed.  I don't know why i have **mainDoc.getElementById('proxyIframe')** there, this statement is used for get the iframe with name **"proxyIframe"**, but i totally don't need do like that, because i can use **window** or **window.document** directly, because what's i try to get is just itself. So no issue now! Cheers!  Anyway, without you comments, i couldn't fix the issue so soonly, thanks!